# How to find which github repos are using LFS

Tags: git, github

How can I find which of my repos are using [github LFS](https://github.com/github/git-lfs) ?

Comment: Git lfs write some config in the git config file so, once cloned, you could grep to verify if it is enabled...

Comment: I know but I have couple dozens of Git repos.

Comment: It's what I imagine but you could easily write a script that do a shallow clone and grep the config file for each of the repositories in a list...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just search your organization for `.gitattributes` files which mention `lfs` like so:

```
org:YOUR_ORG_NAME_HERE filename:.gitattributes "lfs"
```

(Copy this into GitHub's search field.)

Background is, Git LFS seems to tell git about which files are stored in LFS by putting some filters and other attributes for the LFS tracked files into the `.gitattributes` file.

I know this answer comes a bit late, but maybe it helps someone else when running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can easily find this is go to your settings on git hub and then look for payment and billing in the Access Section, Scroll Down to GIT LFS Section and click on Storage.

Answer (score 0):

These [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-git-large-file-storage/viewing-your-git-large-file-storage-usage) describe how to find the UI that shows LFS usage and other restricted or chargeable GitHub.com features.

If you have a GitHub.com enterprise area it breaks down the usage by org. Then each org can list the usage of its individual repos. In both cases the data is under the Billing section.

I am still not sure of a good way of achieving the same on our internal GitHub Enterprise server as there is no Billing section and I haven't found any UI in the Enterprise, org, repo, Management Console, or a CLI `ghe-*` command that mentions LFS.

You could run a script to scan each repo but such an approach can take a very long time if you have large volumes of orgs and repos (we have ~1000 orgs and 30,000+ repos). Also such a process doesn't easily give a nice usage summary. To get that you would need to find each [LFS pointer file](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/spec.md) in each repo and sum all the size fields e.g.

```
version https://github-enterprise.mycompany.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:4d7a214614ab2935c943f9e0ff69d22eadbb8f32b1258daaa5e2ca24d17e2393
size 12345
```

Fortunately storage restrictions are far looser for our internal systems so it hasn't been an issue yet.